# How to make element visible while web scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract some information from fortune best 100 companies to work for link.

I am actually going through each company and extracting the information. Below is the code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
import time

init_url='http://fortune.com/best-companies/google-alphabet-1/'


i=1
while i<=4:
    page=urlopen(init_url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    first_table=soup.find('table',{"class":"company-data-table"})
    th1=first_table.find('th',text='Industry')
    td1=th1.findNext('td')
    print(td1.text)
    th2=first_table.find('th',text='Type of organization')
    td2=th2.findNext('td')
    print(td2.text)

    driver=webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(init_url)
    time.sleep(5)
    elem1=driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next Company")
    elem1.click()
    init_url=driver.current_url
    driver.quit()

    i+=1
```

However, this code is constantly giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/panda_try.py", line 28, in <module>
    elem1.click()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not visible
```

How should I rectify this? I am running against time on this and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are *multiple elements matching the "link text" locator*. You should filter the visible link and then click it:

```
for link in driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Next Company"):
    if link.is_displayed():
        link.click()
        break
```

---

Or, an another way that might work and would by extension replace the unreliable `time.sleep()` is the [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and the `element_to_be_clickable` Expected Condition:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get(init_url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Next Company")))
link.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would use in such case is an XPath selector and also 
WebDriverWait for the element that has to be clicked. I also made some changes, like loading the Browser once, which allows you to run the task faster. In my case selenium was not able to run with the latest Firefox, so I have used an older selenium version (2.49) and Firefox 33 which is set with the FirefoxBinary when loading the web driver.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

init_url = 'http://fortune.com/best-companies/google-alphabet-1/'
next_company_xpath = "//article[contains(@class, 'current')]//div[contains(@class, 'pagination')]//a[contains(.,'Next Company')]"

# Load the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary('firefox/firefox'))
driver.set_window_size(1980, 1080)
driver.get(init_url)

i = 1
while i <= 4:
    page = urlopen(init_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    first_table = soup.find('table', {"class": "company-data-table"})
    th1 = first_table.find('th', text='Industry')
    td1 = th1.findNext('td')
    print(td1.text)
    th2 = first_table.find('th', text='Type of organization')
    td2 = th2.findNext('td')
    print(td2.text)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, next_company_xpath)))
    link.click()
    init_url = driver.current_url

    i += 1

driver.close()
```

Comment: In this line

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary('firefox/firefox'))

Do we need to specify the path where the setup file is stored?

Upon running the code, following error is generated:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You can also do it without that part. Just call the webdriver as you did before: webdriver.Firefox()